# find best fit 3d object

Tags: computational-geometry, best-fit

I have a uneven 3d object and need to fit another 3d symmetrical shape (Cone or cylinder) into this. I need to rotate and expand / shrink the symmetrical shape so that we can find the largest fitting cone / cylinder into this rough object.

I have looked at few bin packing problems but all seem to be dealing with rectangular shapes only ( container as well as the object to fit) and do not seem to be exactly meet my requirements.

The algorithm should also be having optimal performance.

Comment: How do you describe the 3D rough object? With a triangular mesh?

Comment: yup, I have the raw data which gives me 3d co-ordinates of the surface points. We can convert it into a traingular mesh easily.

Answer (score 1):

What about the paper:

FOLLERT, Frank, et al. Computing a largest empty anchored cylinder, and related problems. *International Journal of Computational Geometry & Applications*, 1997, 7.06: 563-580.

The abstract says:

> Let S be a set of n points in ℝd, and let each point p of S have a
>   positive weight w(p). We consider the problem of computing a ray R
>   emanating from the origin (resp. a line l through the origin) such
>   that minp∈S w(p) · d(p, R) (resp. minp∈S w(p) · d(p, l)) is maximal.
>   If all weights are one, **this corresponds to computing a silo
>   emanating from the origin (resp. a cylinder whose axis contains the
>   origin) that does not contain any point of S and whose radius is
>   maximal**. For d=2, we show how to solve these problems in O(n log n)
>   time, which is optimal in the algebraic computation tree model. For
>   d=3, we give algorithms that are based on the parametric search
>   technique and run in O(n log5 n) time. The previous best known
>   algorithms for these three-dimensional problems had almost quadratic
>   running time. In the final part of the paper, we consider some related
>   problems.

A pdf is [here](http://people.scs.carleton.ca:8008/~michiel/cylinder.pdf).